# Is there a way to set a "Maximum Order Total" for PayPal?

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, paypal, ce-1.9.2.2

Is there a way to set a "Maximum Order Total" for PayPal, similarly to the one you can set on other payment methods (without editing core files)?

**Edit: Here is the solution if anyone else is wondering how to do this.**

I manned up and made a small module for this, following a tutorial and grabbing a few code snippets from different threads on here. This Module will hide the PayPal option if the cart total is above 5000 (Currency).

**1.** First create **"app/etc/modules/PPlimit_Module.xml"** with this content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <PPlimit_Module>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Payment/>
            </depends>
        </PPlimit_Module>
    </modules>
</config>
```

**2.** Create **"app/code/local/PPlimit/Module/etc/config.xml"** containing:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <PPlimit_Module>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
    </PPlimit_Module>
</modules>

<global>
    <models>
        <PPlimit_Module>
            <class>PPlimit_Module_Model</class>
        </PPlimit_Module>
    </models>
    <events>
        <payment_method_is_active>
            <observers>
                <pplimit_module>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>PPlimit_Module/Observer</class>
                    <method>paymentMethodIsActive</method>
                </pplimit_module>
            </observers>
        </payment_method_is_active>
    </events>
</global>

</config>
```

**3.** Create **"app/code/local/PPlimit/Module/Model/Observer.php"** with this code:

```
 <?php

class PPlimit_Module_Model_Observer
{
    public function paymentMethodIsActive($observer)
    {
        $instance = $observer->getMethodInstance();
        $result = $observer->getResult();


        if ($instance->getCode() == "paypal_express" || $instance->getCode() =="paypal_standard") {         //Payment Method

        $total = $observer->getQuote()->getGrandTotal();

            if ($total<=5000) {                                 //Payment Limit
                $result->isAvailable = true;
            } else {
                $result->isAvailable = false;
            }
        }
    }

  }

?>
```

That's it, tell me if you find a bug!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is create an extension that listens to an event before the sale is complete and check whether the order total meets your requirement for Paypal orders. There are tutorials on how to do these things in details, but here are the general steps.

1. Set up an extension.
2. Create an observer that listens to `sales_order_place_before`.
3. In this observer, you'll have the order object available. From the order object, you can get the payment method code with something like `$order->getPayment()->getMethod()`.
4. Check the method string amd determine if it's Paypal. If it is, check the order total (`$order->getGrandTotal()`).
5. If the grand total exceeds the maximum, throw an exception of some sort (`throw new Exception('Order amount is too much...')`.
6. When this exception is thrown, you'll get a popup message at checkout with this message, and the order will not go through.

You can hardcode the conditions, or you can create a system configuration interface for the admin to set up conditions for specific payment methods. Again, there are many tutorials out there to do this.

Comment: Thought as much. How "bad" would it be, if I hid the option with a JavaScript snippet if the total order amount exceeds a limit?

Comment: Option to place the order? I think this will be "bad" in a sense that it's not a solution that will prevent me from placing the order, if I knew about the Javascript. It would be a superficial solution, but I suppose it will work most of the time.

Comment: I'll do that as a workaround until I have the time and knowledge to build the extension, thanks!

Comment: Do you have your Magento code base under source control with Git?

Comment: No, seems like a good idea though.

Comment: I made a module around your suggestion, thanks again.

Comment: @Aardi Can u please share your code here. I have the same requirements

Comment: @Nafisa I've edited the post to include the solution. :)

Answer (score 1):

The module Aardi created works for me if I change line 13 in Observer.php with

```
$total = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getGrandTotal();
```